# problem in installing CV3 package in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, pytorch, opencv3.0

```
!pip install cv3
```

I was trying to install cv3 package on google collab but it is throwing the error below:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv3
```

Comment: do you mean opencv v3?

Answer (score 0):

Colab already has opencv installed

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

result : 4.1.2

Comment: @anonymous You can check the answer to help other person knows it's your solution :)